# ReferenceError while exporting a function from Node

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I am coding a test file to test a backend written in Express with jest but what I can't understand is how Node JS manage the export of function with parameters. I have the following code:

```
function checkCredentials( u, p)
{ 
     var check = false;
     if((vectorUsr.indexOf(u)!= -1) && (vectorPswrd.indexOf(p) != -1))
     {
          check = true;
     }
     return check;
}
app.post('/home', function(req, res)
{
    if(checkCredentials(req.body.username, req.body.password))
    {
        req.session.success=true;
        console.log(req.body.username + " submitted Successfully!");
        console.log("POST HOME");
        res.status(200).render('home',{success: req.session.success});
    }
    else
    {
        req.session.success = false;
        res.status(403).redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

At the end of the file I have added these two lines to do the test:

```
exports.checkCredentials = checkCredentials(u,p);
module.exports = app;
```

On the test.js (user and password string are values contained in the vectorUser and vectorPswrd) I have written:

```
    describe(' Login', () =>
    { test(' POST request', (done) =>
      { 
           request(app).post('/home').then((req) =>
           {
                expect(app.checkCredentials('user', 
                'password')).toBe(true).then((res) =>
                {
                     expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
                     done();
                })
           })
       })
   })
```

But when I run jest --runInBand the console says

```
ReferenceError: u is not defined

  60 |     }
  61 |     else
> 62 |     {
  63 |         //Ritorno alla pagina di login
  64 |         req.session.success = false;
  65 |         res.status(403).redirect('/');
```

I really don't understand why this error appears

Answer (score 1):

In this section you are referring to a variable `u`:

```
vectorUsr.indexOf(u)
```

But `u` is not defined anywhere.

I expect you intended:

```
if((vectorUsr.indexOf(user)!= -1) && (vectorPswrd.indexOf(pswrd) != -1))
```

Comment: I have made  typo while I was writing the question sorry, now the script of the question is correct

Comment: Ah. I notice that the ReferenceError does not correspond to the code. I suspect one is out of date. Can you update one or the other to make sure the error message is consistent with the code?